# Conditional increment of array elements' field in mongodb by an amount higher than Long.MAX_VALUE

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents in Mongo (server version 4.0.27), each of which has an array of versions. Each version has an `Int64` revision field. Revisions used to start with `Long.MIN_VALUE` and increment by 1 each time a change was made to the version. We then decided to start revisions with 1. Now we need to increment all revisions that are less than zero by `LONG.MAX_VALUE + 1` for all versions of all existing documents in the collection to level things out.

How can I do this using a script? I need to do this transactionally in that there be no intervening reads from / writes to the document between when the revision value is read by the script and when it's incremented.

I cannot use something like:

```
use database
db.collection.update(                                                                         
    {"versions.revision": {$lt: 0}},                                            
    {$inc: {"versions.$[elem].revision": NumberLong("9223372036854775809")}},                 
    {arrayFilters: [{"elem.revision": {$lt: 0}}], "multi": true}              
)
```

because the number that I need to increment by is bigger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.
I was thinking that I can do two updates in a row to each version along the lines of

```
use database
db.collection.update(                                                                         
    {"versions.revision": {$lt: 0}},                                            
    {$inc: {"versions.$[elem].revision": NumberLong("9223372036854775807")},
     $inc: {"versions.$[elem].revision": NumberLong("2")}},                 
    {arrayFilters: [{"elem.revision": {$lt: 0}}], multi: true}              
)
```

but that executes only the second update (increment by two).

I thought I could use the aggregation pipeline and write:

```
use database
db.collection.update(                                                                         
    {"versions.revision": {$lt: 0}},                                            
    {$set: {"versions.$[elem].revision": {$add: ["versions.$[elem].revision", NumberLong("9223372036854775807"), NumberLong(2)]}}},            
    {arrayFilters: [{"elem.revision": {$lt: 0}}], multi: true}              
)
```

but this is available in server version 4.2 and on.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this in two script commands / passes. During the first pass, I increment revision numbers by `Long.MAX_VALUE` and set a temporary flag for the updated element so I could find it during the second pass. On the second pass, I search for the updated elements, increment the revisions by two and clear the flag:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    {"versions.revision": {$lt: 0}},
    {$inc: {"versions.$[elem].revision": NumberLong("9223372036854775807")}, $set: {"versions.$[elem].temp": true}},
    {arrayFilters: [{"elem.revision": {$lt: 0}}], multi:true}
)

db.collection.updateMany(
    {"versions.temp": true},
    {$inc: {"versions.$[elem].revision": NumberLong("2")}, $unset: {"versions.$[elem].temp": ""}},
    {arrayFilters: [{"elem.temp": true}]}
)
```

I'm still eager to see if this can be done with a single command.